# ROS Repositories by Organisation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I remember seeing a wiki article which broke down ROS packages by organisation. For example several universities had some ROS repositories and there was a link to them.

Was this on this page http://wiki.ros.org/Repositories?

I personally found it useful to get links to repositories by Organisation. Because you could explore what work was being done by a university.

Currently its a bit overwhelming searching through all ROS packages.

I would be happy to help maintain such a page.

Edit:
**Ok I see that was the page I remembered. But it wasn't really grouped by organisation it was just a list of packages**

However I noticed, I couldn't search for a lot of the packages on the original page for example.
I could not find:
berkeley-ros-pkg
or the mit ros packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221990/ros-repositories-by-organisation/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-05**:
Personally I use [ROS Index](http://rosindex.github.io/). Its db needs to be updated, but other than that it's a pretty handy site. Perhaps we could convince @jbohren to run the update scripts some time?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2015-12-07**:
@gvdhoorn Unfortunately, ROS Index is statically-hosted by GitHub, so I need to run the updates locally, verify, and then push them. I'd like to make the updates more frequent though. I've set up a campaign to try to fund it here (no announcement yet): https://salt.bountysource.com/teams/rosindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately that sort of information is not systematically captured anywhere.

Those repsitory names were a legacy of subversion. Where each organization would have one big repository with lots of subprojects. However as our community has moved toward using git. There's a lot more granular source control per repository. Associating multiple repositories together is not done automatically. It would have to be a manual process.

If anything maybe extending something like ROS Index to support cross referencing by author/maintainer would get you a good amount of grouping.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2